# Patching nested objects in Python

Tags: python, mocking, pytest

Two problems:
I'm trying to mock out PasswordClient().password_db so it can be used in TableQuery.  I having trouble mocking out `PasswordClient.__init__()`.

```
import os
class PasswordClient:
    def __init__(self):
        self.password_db = os.environ['DOES_NOT_EXIST']

class DBClient:
    def __init__(self):
        password_client = PasswordClient()

class TableQuery():
    def add_person(self):
        self.db_client=DBClient() 

@patch.object(PasswordClient, 'PasswordClient.__init__')
def fn():
    return 'hello'

a = TableQuery()
a.add_person()
```

I've tried with the following:

```
@patch.object(PasswordClient, 'PasswordClient.__init__')
@patch.object(PasswordClient, 'PasswordClient.password_db')
@patch.object(PasswordClient, 'password_db')
```

All end with KeyError because DOES_NOT_EXIST well ... you know.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A better design would be to pass the necessary clients as arguments, rather than make each class responsible for knowing how to instantiate such a client.

```
import os


class PasswordClient:
    def __init__(self, value):
        self.password_db = value

class DBClient:
    def __init__(self, pc):
        self.password_client = pc


class TableQuery:
    def __init__(self, dbc):
        self.db_client = dbc

    def add_person(self):
        ...



a = TableQuery(DBClient(PasswordClient(...)))
a.add_person()
```